# How to install grunt outside of a project and run tasks from the project directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm watching this series of tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXbHv2INOIQ) and I can see that the grunt ( not the grunt-cli ) files are stored in the project root.

I see that this is normally the case but wanted to put my files elsewhere.

Is there a way to do this.  Obviously I could run the init to create the package.json file in say `/grunt` and do the install there, but would it be relatively easy to tell it how to interface with my project `/root/project`.

Comment: Simple question to understand your question. Why do you want to put the grunt task outside a project? When you means outside, you mean for example outside of the git repository? Could you add to your question the structure that you would like to have, please?

Comment: I think must do a grunt install for each project.  I just want one installation in my root directory.

Comment: How your team mates will work with you if grunt tasks are not on the git repository? How do you write efficient and clean task if you are writing them for 3 different projects?That is clearly the wrong way man. I recommend you to write grunt tasks for each project. Read this post to know how to organize your tasks : [Organize your grunt tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804659/how-to-create-and-organise-config-and-register-grunt-tasks) :)

Comment: I only have one project.  Plus the two config files that grunt uses I do push to my repo.  They are linked in symbolically.

Comment: ok, I understand. then what is your problem?

Comment: What is the process for installing grunt in my root directory and having it available globally ?

Comment: what do you means by globally? I will give you an example as an answer.

Comment: I mean I want to be able to run `grunt watch` and have it watch my files no matter where I am ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95969/discussion-between-louis-barranqueiro-and-cade-galt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an potential example of your structure :

```
main-folder
├── package.json
├── Gruntfile.js
├── grunt
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── copy.js
│   │   │   ├── sass.js
│   │   │   ├── sync.js
│   │   │   ├── linkAsset.js
│   │   │   └── uglify.js
│   ├── register
│   │   │   ├── compileAssets.js
│   │   │   ├── linkAssets.js
│   │   │   ├── build.js
│   │   │   └── buildProd.js
├── project-1
│   └── folders and files ...
├── project-2
│   └── folders and files ...
```

- **package.json** : contains all your grunt-plugins dependencies and other useful npm modules
- **Gruntfile.js** :  load and configure all tasks in `grunt/config` and `grunt/register` folder

Read this if you want to have more information to setup this configuration of grunt : [How to create and organise config and register grunt tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805887/3755845)

**Configuration file** :

I recommend you also to use a configuration file (**E.g**  : `main-folder/grunt/config.js`) file to register some shortcut, variables to make your grunt tasks more dynamic.

Example :

```js
var version = '0.1.0';
var project1Dir = 'project-1';
var project2Dir = 'project-2';

module.exports.version = version;
module.exports.project1Dir = project1Dir;
module.exports.project2Dir = project2Dir;
```

And import this config in each task with : `var config = require('../config');`. It will be easy to refactor the code if you rename for example the folder `project1`.

**Run tasks** :

Now when you are working in your directory (`main-folder/project1`or `main-folder/project2`) and entering your grunt command, use `b` flag to tell to grunt where is your `Gruntfile.js` file.

Example :

```bash
grunt -b ../ build
```

You can also configure in the code this behavior. Read Grunt documentation for more information : [Grunt CLI - b flag](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#base-b)

Comment: thanks dude, I drank too much vodka, I'll read this tomorrow.