# How to create and organise config and register grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a project where I'm using `grunt` to process my `Js` and `SASS` files.

At the moment, when I need to process something, I need to call all the tasks inside my `gruntfile.js` even if I want to change only one module, or only the `SASS` file.

Is there a way to create a custom task, to run only the sass part, and another one to create only a module process, where I can call this task from the prompt?

This is what I tried, without success:

```
    module.exports = function(gruntHome) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /* @CONCAT */
        concat: {
            home : {
                src: 'src/app/component/home/*.js',
                dest: 'src/app/component/home/concat/concat_config.js'
            }
        },

        /* @ANNOTATE */
        ngAnnotate: {
            options: {
                add: true
            },
            home: {
                files: {
                    'src/app/component/home/concat/concat_config.js': 'src/app/component/home/concat/concat_config.js'
                }
            }
        },

        /* @UGLIFY */
        uglify: {
            home: {
                src:  'src/app/component/home/concat/concat_config.js',
                dest: 'app/component/home/home.min.js'
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');

    grunt.registerTask('gruntTask', ['concat', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify']);
};
```

If it's not possible, is there any other way to achieve this objective?
Because my gruntfile.js is huge, and sometimes it takes a lot of time to process, even if I don't need to process everything.

---

#### Edit:

This [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813073/task-not-found-using-grunt/33814039#33814039) is a related question I made following the steps provided on this question. It will solve some possible issues you have when trying to do what i did here. Hope it can help other people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how, you can organise your grunt tasks :

- **config** : Default tasks
- **register** : Alias tasks which call multiple default tasks

**Some rules that you have to respect** :

- the name of your file must be the same name of your task (E.g : ngAnnotate.js -> task : ngAnnotate)
- group your configurations tasks by grunt plugins in one file. **Don't mix grunt-plugins in configuration tasks, Register tasks are there for this job.**
- name of configuration task and register tasks are shared then you can't set a `home` configuration task and a `home` register task because when you call it with grunt home, grunt isn't able to know the task that you are refering to.

```js
├── Gruntfile.js
└── grunt
    ├── config
    │   ├── sass.js
    │   ├── concat.js
    │   └── uglify.js
    └── register
        ├── GroupOfTasks.js
        └── AnotherGroupOfTasks.js
```

Your `Gruntfile.js` will load and configure all tasks in `grunt/config` and `grunt/register` folder with this code :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    // Load the include-all library in order to require all of our grunt
    // configurations and task registrations dynamically.
    var includeAll;

    try {
        includeAll = require('include-all');
    }
    catch (e0) {
        console.error('Could not find `include-all` module.');
        console.error('Skipping grunt tasks...');
        console.error('To fix this, please run:');
        console.error('npm install include-all --save-dev');
        console.error();
    }

    /**
     * Loads Grunt configuration modules from the specified
     * relative path. These modules should export a function
     * that, when run, should either load/configure or register
     * a Grunt task.
     */
    function loadTasks(relPath) {
        return includeAll({
                dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, relPath),
                filter:  /(.+)\.js$/
            }) || {};
    }

    /**
     * Invokes the function from a Grunt configuration module with
     * a single argument - the `grunt` object.
     */
    function invokeConfigFn(tasks) {
        for (var taskName in tasks) {
            if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(taskName)) {
                tasks[taskName](grunt);
            }
        }
    }

    // Load task functions
    var taskConfigurations  = loadTasks('./grunt/config'),
        registerDefinitions = loadTasks('./grunt/register');

    // Run task functions to configure Grunt.
    invokeConfigFn(taskConfigurations);
    invokeConfigFn(registerDefinitions);

};
```

Your config task should look like that (E.g : `sass.js`) :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('sass', {
        dev: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false
            },
            files: {
                'main.css': 'main.scss'
            } 
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
};
```

You will be able to run config task with `grunt sass` to run all sass task or `grunt sass:dev` to run only one task.

And a register task should look like that (E.g: `SassAndConcat` task to run `sass` and `concat` task) :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('SassAndConcat', [
        'sass:dev',
        'concat:dev',
    ]);
};
```

And now you will be able to run `grunt SassAndConcat`.

If you understand that, you will be able to run your grunt tasks more efficiently by running the right task at the right time.

Don't forget to install `include-all` NPM module to require all of our grunt configurations and task registrations dynamically.

Comment: Nice! Very nice, i think i got it. Just one more thing. How do i call it from the prompt? Right now i just type 'grunt' and it run everything. Should i create multiple modules, with a name of 'sassGrunt', for example, and call it on the prompt 'sassGrunt' ?

Comment: I have updated my anwser with information how to run config and register tasks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It will save me a lot of time! And improve my workflow a lot.

Comment: your welcome :) Check this repository, if you wanna see a full example with many tasks : https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/tranquilpeak-hexo-theme

Comment: Yes! It helped me a little, but @LouisBarranqueiro, can you take a look at this git: https://github.com/celsomtrindade/gruntTest It's the files I'm using to try this solutions. I have 2 proccess, almost the same. 'Sass' and 'Inicio'. 'sass' works fine, but 'inicio' says: `Task 'inicio' not found` Any idea why?

Comment: I did it @LouisBarraqueiro, its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813073/task-not-found-using-grunt would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Excellent answer - it appears you used SailsJS Gruntfile.js code and organization, as it is pretty much the same?

Anyway - I was wondering, I'd like to use jit-grunt to significantly reduce load time of this approach for processors on file watches.  However, based on time sampling with time-grunt and `grunt -v myprocess:dev`, all tasks are loaded!  Any ideas on how to improve this approach with jit-grunt to only load required tasks?

Comment: yeah, this architecture is based on sails.js. Ask this on a new question, i'm gonna check it :)