# Task not found using grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to use multiple tasks in grunt, one of them is working partialy, and the other is getting erros of `not found task`.

This question is based [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804659/how-to-create-and-organise-config-and-register-grunt-tasks), where I'm using the same `gruntfile.js` and the same structure, which is this:

```
├── Gruntfile.js
└── grunt
    ├── config
    │   ├── conf_sass.js
    │   └── conf_home.js
    └── register
        ├── reg_sass.js
        └── reg_home.js
```

With this respective files:

conf_sass.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('sass', {

        sass: {
            options: {
                style:'expanded',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {
                'src/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.scss'
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'dist/css/app.min.css': 'src/css/app.css'
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

reg_sass.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compSass', ['sass']);
};
```

conf_home.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('home', {

        concat: {
            dist : {
                src: 'src/.../home/*.js',
                dest: 'src/.../concat_home.js'
            }
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            options: {
                add: true
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'src/.../concat_home.js': 'src/.../concat_home.js'
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                src:  'src/.../concat_home.js',
                dest: 'app/.../home.min.js'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');
};
```

reg_home.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compHome', ['home']);
};
```

The problem is:

The sass process, runs everything without erros, but doesn't execute the css minify part, even with no errors at all.

The home process, return an error

> Warning: task 'home' not found

What's wrong with it? I have all the modules installed because they were all working before moving to this new structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems :
- the name of your file must be the same name of your task (**E.g** : `ngAnnotate.js` -> task : `ngAnnotate`)
- your task are not grouped by grunt plugins
- name of configuration task and register tasks are shared then you can't set a `home` configuration task and a `home` register task because when you call it with `grunt home`, grunt isn't able to know the task that you are refering to.

You have to respect this rules for configuration task : **group configuration tasks that use a same plugins in one file, don't mix grunt-plugins in configuration tasks, Register tasks are there for this job.**

The problem with your current configuration, to call **cssmin** task, you have to run `grunt sass:cssmin` and it doesn't make sense. That's why by grouping configuration tasks by grunt plugins, you call your **cssmin** task with `grunt cssmin` or a subtask in it with `grunt cssmin:<subtask_name>`

Here is an example :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('sass', { 
        website: {
            options: {
                style:'expanded',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {
                'src/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.scss'
            }
        },
        admin: {
            options: {
                style:'expanded',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {
                'src/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.scss'
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
};
```

Here we have registered the **sass** configuration task, to run it , we use `grunt sass`. It will run all subtask in it **website** and **admin** sub tasks.
Now, if we want to run only website task, we run :  `grunt sass:website`

Then in your case, here is what your structure should look like :

```js
├── Gruntfile.js
└── grunt
    ├── config
    │   ├── sass.js
    │   ├── concat.js
    │   ├── cssmin.js
    │   ├── uglify.js
    │   └── ngAnnotate.js
    └── register
        ├── sassAndCssmin.js
        └── home.js
```

your `sass.js` file :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('sass', {
        sass: {
            options: {
                style:'expanded',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {
                'src/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.scss'
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
};
```

your `cssmin.js` file :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('cssmin', {
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'dist/css/app.min.css': 'src/css/app.css'
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

your `concat.js` file :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('concat', {
        home: {
            dist : {
                src: 'src/.../home/*.js',
                dest: 'src/.../concat_home.js'
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```

your `ngAnnotate.js` file :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('ngAnnotate', {
        home: {
            options: {
                add: true
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'src/.../concat_home.js': 'src/.../concat_home.js'
                }
            }
        },

    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');
};
```

Same process for other configuration tasks.

And here is an example with the register tasks :

your `sassAndCssmin.js` file:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('sassAndCssmin', [
        'sass',
        'cssmin'
    ]);
};
```

your `home.js` file :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('home', [
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'uglify'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Another awesome explanation! Thank you very much Louis, it made a lot clear for me to understand how all of this grunt process works, and also, to improve the workflow. Thanks again!

Comment: is it possible to have a registerTask like this: `'concat:home', 'ngAnnotate:home', 'uglify:home'` ? Because i want to create multiple files to process only those specific parts, since each of them will contain all of my modules, and I don't to proccess all of them at the same time. Currently I can't do it, there is this error: task not found

Comment: Of course mate! with subtasks, you can run task more efficiently

Comment: But what did i do wrong? I was following your example but got that error just by placing the `:home` part

Comment: your subtask in concat, ngAnnotate and uglify should be named home. I updated my awnser with `ngAnnotate:home` and `concat:home` example

Comment: Oh, i was doing like this `concat: { home: { ..tasks.....` Just had to get rid of the 'concat' at the begining. Thanks one more time. You saved my day! hahahaha