# Which is the best way to divide Gruntfile

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm looking for best way to divide my `Gruntfile.js` where grunt tasks are defined.

Right now I have made it with `require` and look like this:

```
require('./grunt_tasks/task_1')(grunt);
```

And `task_1.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.registerTask('task_1', [
        'sub_task_1',
        'sub_task_2',
        'sub_task_3'
    ]);
};
```

It work nice, but I'm looking for a cleaner way. Thanks.

Comment: Hey man. Here is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804659/how-to-create-and-organise-config-and-register-grunt-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, `load-grunt-config` and in config add `configPath` array for load files.