# Grunt Add multiple input/output directories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, jsx, grunt-babel

I am using `grunt-babel` to transform my `react-jsx` files into `.js`.

I am planning to write a grunt task for this. Currently, I have below

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig( {

        babel : {
            options : {
                plugins : ['transform-react-jsx'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            },
            client : {
                expand : true,
                cwd : './react_demo/test/jsx/common',
                src : ['*.jsx'],
                dest : './react_demo/static/react/components',
                ext : '.js'
            }
        }
    } );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel:client']);

};
```

In my above task what I am trying to do is, I am transforming all my `JSX` files present in folder `./react_demo/test/jsx/common` into `./react_demo/static/react/components`.

Now, in my application in future we can have multiple folder each having there own-set of JSX files which will be going into different destination folders.

We can have folders like:

- /react_demo/test/jsx/common -> /react_demo/static/react/components
- /react/test/jsx/common1 -> /react/static/react/components1
- /react2/test/jsx/common2 -> /react2/static/react/components2

Now, how can I specify multiple `src/dest`directories and map them together? I tried giving an array to src/dest but it complained with below error:

> Warning: Path must be a string. Received [
>   './react_demo/cartridge/scripts/jsx/common' ] Use --force to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to specify a new babel target for each new destination:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig( {

        babel : {
            options : {
                plugins : ['transform-react-jsx'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            },
            client : {
                expand : true,
                cwd : './react_demo/test/jsx/common',
                src : ['*.jsx'],
                dest : './react_demo/static/react/components',
                ext : '.js'
            },
            common1 : {//add more targets
                expand : true,
                cwd : './react/test/jsx/common1',
                src : ['*.jsx'],
                dest : './react/static/react/components1',
                ext : '.js'
            }//etc..

        }
    } );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel:client','babel:common1']);//reg new targets

};
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. But I was thinking there must be a better way to do this. I will wait for few more answers, otherwise I accept yours. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Few days back, I have faced this problem.You can achieve it by using config file.

write a configuration file (E.g : main-folder/grunt/config.js) file to register some shortcut, variables to make your grunt tasks more dynamic.

Example:

```
var demoConfig = { 
    'module1': 'script/module1',
    'module2': 'script/module2',
    'module3': 'script/module3' 
};
module.exports = demoConfig ;
}
```

And import this config in each task with : var config = require('../config');

In gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-task');
var getTasks = function() {
    var jsConfig = require('../config/demoConfig'),
        jsTasks = {};
    for (var key in jsConfig) {
        jsTasks[key] = {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './react_demo/test/jsx/' + jsConfig[key],
                src: '**/*.jsx',
                dest: './react_demo/static/react/' +jsConfig[key],
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        };
    }
    return jsTasks;
};
grunt.config('babel', getTasks());};
```

for your scenario, you can change some functionality here and get it done.

I hope this help.

for more info read this:
[dynamic grunt task with babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696297/how-to-install-grunt-outside-of-a-project-and-run-tasks-from-the-project-directohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696297/how-to-install-grunt-outside-of-a-project-and-run-tasks-from-the-project-directo)